# После переноса вопроса репутация не отнимается?

Tags: дефект

У [участника](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/197183/granular-bastard) всего один [вопрос](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/22789/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-the-church-is-near-but-the-road-is-icy-the-bar-is-far). Этот вопрос перенесли на russian.stackexchange.com. И теперь у пользователя репутация 33 на обоих ресурсах, хотя вопрос один и тот же. Почему так?

Answer (score 2):

Перенесённые вопросы удаляются по истечении 30 дней после миграции. Тогда и происходит пересчёт репутации.

Источник: [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4948/235436) [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson).